# Calling a Service method from Activity

Tags: android

In my activity i have:

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override                           
        public void onClick(View v) {

        service.playSong(MEDIA_PATH);

        }
    });
```

and this is in Service:

```
void playSong(String file) {
        try {

                mp.reset();
                System.out.println(file+songs.get(currentPosition));
                mp.setDataSource(file+ songs.get(currentPosition));

                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                             nextSong();
                     }
             });

        } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

As you see from the code above in my activity when i click the button play I am passing the path into the service in order to play music but it is crashing What is wrong?

Comment: You should add the stacktrace with the Exception from the Logcat.

Comment: Can you please specify it a bit more since I am new into Android??

Comment: I really dont get what are u talking about... can you please show me any example how to do that?

Comment: You app is trowing an Exception. In Eclipse go to the Logcat (in the ddms http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html ) and copy the stacktrace containing you exception(the red text).

Comment: I have declared ServiceMP3 service; at activity class and from activity i try to acces the method of Service by this: service.playSound() is this correct, what else i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind with the `Service` before running that.

Check this links:

- [Communicate with Activity from Service (LocalService) - Android Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908267/communicate-with-activity-from-service-localservice-android-best-practices)
- [Bind service to activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916253/bind-service-to-activity-in-android)

Comment: which of these two is in my case?? i think the second one, right?

Comment: is it that prob to call an Service method?? I still cant get it to work

Comment: @Samuel: Yes. Look for an example of how to bind to a `Service`.

Comment: is it like this?? 
play= (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new StartClick()); 

private class StartClick implements View.OnClickListener {    
     public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainMP3.this,ServiceMP3.class);
      MainMP3.this.bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
     }
    }