# Bind service to FragmentActivity or Fragment?

Tags: android, service, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Is it better to bind service to `FragmentActivity`:

```
bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int);
```

or to `Fragment`:

```
getActivity().bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int);
```

What is better practice?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> Is it better to bind service to FragmentActivity... or to Fragment

They are the same as you have them written here. `getActivity()` is not a `Fragment` -- it is a method that returns the `Activity`. You cannot call `bindService()` on a `Fragment`.

> What is better practice?

Neither. Bind to the `Application` object, obtained via `getApplicationContext()`, with the `ServiceConnection` managed by (or perhaps actually *being*) a retained `Fragment`.

The reason is configuration changes. A binding is state. You need to maintain that state across configuration changes. While a retained `Fragment` can hold onto the `ServiceConnection`, there is an implicit tie in the system between the `ServiceConnection` and the `Context` that registered it for a binding. Since activities can be destroyed and recreated on configuration changes, the `Activity` is not a good choice of `Context` here. `Application`, which is system-global, is a safer choice, and one of the few places where choosing `Application` over another `Context` is a wise move IMHO.

[Here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/09/29/another-use-getapplicationcontext-binding-rotation.html) of mine, from a time before fragments, that gets into this a bit more. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AdvServices/Binding) demonstrating the technique.

Comment: Could you please share your opinion on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309379/bind-service-to-activity-or-fragment

Comment: Looking at your demo, it appears you're leaking memory. You keep a reference to a UI element in a retained Fragment, so an old Context will still be referenced even though the configuration may have changed. I would keep the UI elements in a separate Fragment.

Comment: @mkuech: That UI element is set to a new value in `onCreateView()`. Hence, after the configuration change, the fragment will not be holding onto the old widget anymore.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah, yes, for some reason I had it in my head that `onCreateView()` wasn't called again with a retained fragment. Apologies!

Comment: @mkuech: No problem, though you had me scared there for a minute... :-)